# how to do a Method call

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i try to use: Bootstrap-Wizard: https://github.com/gilluminate/Bootstrap-Wizard

in the documentation it wrote

The url() method changes the URL from which an Ajax (remote) panel will be loaded.
Parameters:
:Index (number) - The zero-based index of the panel of which its URL is to be updated.
:URL (string) - A URL the content of the panel is loaded from.

I don't really understand how to make the call to this method?

```
$("#myElement").bwizard( 'url'(1,  "/project/testUrl"   ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be something like this:

```
$("#myElement").bwizard("url", 1, "/project/testUrl");
```

or this

```
$("#myElement").data("bwizard").url(1, "/project/testUrl");
```